# I am getting Field 'id' doesn't have a default value in my Java Hibernate database

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, database-schema

this is a database that is going to store Temperatures built using Hibernate:

```
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedBy;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@Data
public class TempTable { //Den viktigaste tabellen i DBMS, här lagras data rått
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long Id;

    private Float temperatures;

    @CreatedDate
    @LastModifiedBy
    private LocalDateTime timestamp; // ' 2023-09-24T12:34:56.789 '

    @Transient
    public String getFormattedTimestamp(){ //Denna metod påverkar inte data som finns i tabellerna, den är framtagen för enkelt kunna formatera data
        if (timestamp != null) {
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd 'hour' HH : 'minute' mm : 'seconds' : ss.SSS");
            return timestamp.format(formatter);
        }
        System.out.println("Could not format datetime");
        return "";
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tempTable", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<WarningTable> warningTables = new ArrayList<>();

    public TempTable(Long Id, Float temperatures){
        this.Id = Id;
        this.temperatures = temperatures;
    }
}
```

When I try to run this SQL query in workbench: `INSERT INTO temp_table (temperatures) VALUES (22.5);`

I get this error
`0    16  18:30:49    INSERT INTO temp_table (temperatures) VALUES (22.5) Error Code: 1364. Field 'id' doesn't have a default value   0.000 sec`

This is very strange? The id is supposed to auto-increment, I have put the correct annotations. So can anyone please point out any issues?

Or is the problem due to the fact that my database is empty?

This is how the table looks at the moment:

````
   id,             bigint,         NO,         PRI,     NULL,
   temperatures,   float,          YES,,                NULL,
   timestamp,      datetime(6),    YES,,                NULL,```

I converted the table into a csv file so that I could gather information about the table
````

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't want to add this behavior in a SQL query, this should already be built into the java code. 

The purpose of this database isn't so that I would need to do modifications inside of workbench or something similiar

I know I can add ``` ALTER TABLE temp_table MODIFY id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
````

Into workbench, but then that would just make the Hibernate database useless

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up: when you use `GenerationType.AUTO` with Hibernate, it typically opts for a `SEQUENCE` in the database rather than the `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature. This means the default value for this column would be `null` in the database.

If you're looking to change this, consider using `GenerationType.IDENTITY` or `GenerationType.TABLE`. For instance, `GenerationType.TABLE` will leverage the `AUTO_INCREMENT` feature in databases like MariaDB.

Hope this helps!

Comment: EEEEHH AA! Thank you so much, it works now!!